# <input type="file"> open browser window in IE6 on clicking on text field area as Firefox

Tags: javascript

`<input type="file">` in IE6 when I write something in field text area it is writable but not in firefox and chrome. I want to open browser window in IE6 on clicking on text field area as same as Firefox.

Comment: You mean something like

`<input type="file" onfocus="if (document.all) this.click()" />` - don't try to change the behaviour of the browser. Your page will be the only one that IE6 user has seen where the file selector opens when trying to upload a file

Answer (score 0):

The file input field's look and feel and behabior are different from browser to browser. It's not easy to change this. You are better off using a plugin that hides the file input field and replaces it with a custom one. Like the one here - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-prettyfile.
With jQuery you may also try the following code -

$('input[type="file"]').focus(function(){$(this).click();$('body').focus();});

I don't have IE6 so can't check it; but it works on IE7 and 8.